# React Dev Tools not loading components and Events not firing

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I can't tell if my two issues are related, but I figured there might be a chance so here goes.

I'm playing around with React (using webpack / commonjs) and I'm having a basic level of success. Components render on the page successfully.

Unfortunately, no events are working (even testing simple click handlers) and also my React dev tools do not load my hierarchy at all, just showing `<Top Level></Top Level>`. I've tried the expose-loader (for handling the dev tools issue) to no avail.

Any ideas at all much appreciated!

edit: It's probably worth mentioning that I know my event handlers are being loaded (if i pass as a handler a reference to a function which logs to the console, for instance, the messages appears). The events themselves simply aren't firing/being directed to the handlers.

edit 2: Also worth noting (based on the commonly suggested solutions for this problem) that I have also tried just exposing React to the window for the dev tools, and that if I go somewhere like the React homepage my react dev tools work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. In my case, I was using browserify, bower, and debowerify. My React app was spread across several modules. In one of the modules, I was importing `react/react-with-addons`, while in the other modules I was just importing vanilla `react`. Once I updated all my imports to use `react/react-with-addons`, the problem went away. For example, I initially had something like:

```
// module1.js
var React = require("react");

// module2.js
var React = require("react/react-with-addons");
```

When I changed it to the following, everything started working again:

```
// module1.js
var React = require("react/react-with-addons");

// module2.js
var React = require("react/react-with-addons");
```